# Amazon Ec2 api call though Postman Rest client

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, postman

I have tried to use postman rest client to access amazon web service to get availability zone as "https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeAvailabilityZones" get type , I am selecting authorization as AWSSignature, but am getting Http Status code as 401 unauthorized status in response. I don't know what should i give in service name while selecting AWSSignature ? I tried to give service name as ec2 and aws. Can any one help on this ?

Comment: This might help
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html

Comment: You may also try this cli (install them first), but for this you've to supply the access key and secret key
`aws ec2 describe-availability-zones`
and
`aws ec2 describe-availability-zones`